# Trigger for a board game not working as intended

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm a complete newbie and I am having issues creating a trigger that needs to be executed when the Players table is updated. It first has to check if on_location exists as a location_id in the table Real_estate and to also check if anyone else owns the location_id already (owned_by = NULL if no one owns it).

Once those two conditions are satisfied I need to update the owned_by column in the Real_estate table so that instead of NULL it will have the player_id.

Additionally, I need to update the player_balance in the Players table by subtracting the estate_cost from original player_balance.

This is what I have now:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS R1;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER R1 AFTER UPDATE ON Players FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.on_location = (SELECT location_id FROM Real_estate WHERE location_id = NEW.on_location) 
AND
(SELECT owned_by FROM Real_estate WHERE location_id = NEW.on_location)  = NULL 
THEN

UPDATE Real_estate
SET
owned_by = (SELECT player_id FROM Players WHERE on_location = NEW.on_location)
WHERE location_id = NEW.on_location;

UPDATE Players
SET
player_balance = (player_balance - (SELECT estate_cost FROM Real_estate WHERE location_id = NEW.on_location))
WHERE player_id = (SELECT player_id FROM Players WHERE on_location = NEW.on_location);

END IF;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: You cannot update `Players` table in the trigger defined on this table. You must alter the data to be saved during this UPDATE and set it to needed value in BEFORE trigger.

Comment: You must use miltiple-table UPDATE syntax instead of your strange subqueries.